# Как стилизовать select на JavaScript и CSS ?

Tags: html, javascript, css

Как стилизовать select на JavaScript(не JQUery) и CSS, я иска нашел то [что нужно](http://mihalytch.org.ua/programming/js/styled-drop-down-list.html)
но там уже ничего нельзя скачать и разобраться, помогите схему действий накидать (ну разобратся короче)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я вот так реализовал: [Свой select html javascript css](http://lampacore.ru/2012/11/23/%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-select-html-javascript-css/)

Answer (score 4):

Создай слой `div` с абсолютной позицией с фиксированной шириной и высотой
в его стиль так же напиши

```
overflow-x:none;
overflow-y:scroll;
```

или так

```
overflow-x:none;
overflow-y:auto;
```

Пихни в главный див кучу дивов, каждый див со своим словом (что будет в селекте).

Вот и все.

Потом показывай главный слой при щелчке на кто-нибудь.

**вот слой**

```
<div class="select">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
</div>
```

**стиль к нему**

```
.select {
   width:90px;
   height:150px;
   position:absolute;
   left:0px;
   top:30px;
   border:1px solid #ff0000;
   overflow-x:none;
   overflow-y:auto;
}
.select div {
   cursor:pointer;
}
.select div:hover {
   background:#555555;
}
```

Можно использовать фоновые картинки и т.д.

Для того чтобы сделать чтобы этот слой всплывал по нажатию со стрелочкой вниз
нужно создать еще слой.

```
<div style="position:relative; width:92px;">
    <div style="height:30px;">нажми чтобы выбрать</div>
    <!-- сюда нужно воткнуть слой селекта который написан выше -->
</div>
```

примерно как то так, не проверял то что получилось
но должно работать

Comment: спасибо большое но я уже сам справился :)))

Comment: если интересно то во тут http://plus.onzagame.ru/ в регистрации выбор пола ...

Comment: и буду счастлив если кто нибудь подскажет почему так анимация глючит ?

Comment: @Kirpich643, до решения проблем с анимацией, я бы советовал исправить более ощутимые баги. Например, [вот что я вижу](http://tinyurl.com/a7vyllo) после начала "регистрации" (первое окно не скрывается до конца). Кликаю на выбор пола, но если не выбираю, то список не скрывается. Когда начиная набирать свой email, "подсказки" всплывают в [загадочном месте](http://i.piccy.info/i7/bf65172da547474694c50d59f88a225a/4-55-310/48962180/lag2.jpg).

Answer (score 2):

Это же не единственный ресур в инете. Потратил целых две минуты:

1. [Custom Drop-Down List Styling](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/04/custom-drop-down-list-styling/).
2. [Styling Drop Down Boxes with jQuery](http://www.devirtuoso.com/2009/08/styling-drop-down-boxes-with-jquery/).
3. [Styling Dark Select Dropdown With Dropkick.js](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/site-elements/styling-dark-select-dropdown-with-dropkick-js/).

Comment: Ты просто гуру интернета ! я блин два дня просрал чтоб этот единственный стухший найти)))

Comment: @Kirpich643, правильно составленный запрос в поисковике и никакой магии или гуру ))

Comment: здесь то что вы по находили все при помощи jQuery... Это мне не подходит ((((((((

Answer (score 0):

Есть очень хороший, универсальный [jQuery плагин Select2](http://crudox.ru/select2-jquery-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-select/) с широкими возможностями.

Comment: В вопросе указано - __не jQuery__. Не забывайте, что JavaScript не исчерпывается jQuery